# How to find multiple groups of solutions that meet the requirements

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, random

I want to find multiple nonzero real matrices `A`, `B` that satisfy $A.B=\mathbf{0}$ condition.

```
A = Array[a, {3, 3}];
B = Array[b, {3, 3}];
FindInstance[
 A.B == ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}] && A != ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}] && 
  B != ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}], Flatten[{A, B}], Reals,5]
{{A, B}} /. First[%]
```

However, the above code can not return the desired results for a long time. What can I do to quickly get multiple sets of matrices that meet the requirements (their elements are preferably rational numbers)?

Comment: Is there some reason to avoid using `NullSpace`?

Answer (score 2):

With that many unknowns I am astonished that this completes in less than HUGE amounts of time.

```
{{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}},{{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{p,q,r}}}/.
FindInstance[{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}.{{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{p,q,r}}==
{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}&&Element[a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r,Reals],
{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r},3]
```

All the results I've seen have rational or integer entries.
It does seem to tend towards solutions with one or more zero rows.
If a zero row is acceptable then replacing a,b,c with 0,0,0 seems to speed it up significantly. Eliminating the `Element[,Reals]` speeds it up even more, but that results in a lot of Complex values.